# Apply CSS class to li not child li

Tags: html, css

I have a class specified for a list:

```
.nav ul li.current {
    background: #fff;
}
```

The problem is, I only want to style the parent li element, not any children.

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li class="current">Something else</li> <!-- apply class here -->
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>Child something</li>
        <li class="current">Child something else</li> <!-- ...but not here -->
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS pasted above is changing the background for both li elements with the class "current". How do I correct this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
.nav > ul > li.current { ... }
```

Comment: @jbabey how come: "I only want to style the parent li element, not any children."?

Comment: removed my comment, didn't read clearly, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav > ul > li.current {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This will apply the style to the inner li as well, which is OP is trying to avoid.